# Error, missing calls inside every; when running tests together

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, testing, mockito

I am having `io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.` exception from the test below. The weird part is I am not getting this error when the class run by itself. The error occurs if I run this test class with others. I don't have any static fields in the other class and I am sure all fields created as `MoneyCalculator` are private and cannot be reached from other classes.

The Error occurs when mocking `moneyCalculator`, is there any idea about why this error occurs?

```
class AccountingJournalLineItemServiceTest : AbstractAccountingUnitTest() {

    @MockK
    private lateinit var moneyCalculator: MoneyCalculator

    @InjectMockKs
    private lateinit var service: Service

    @Test
    fun testCreateResponsePayload_whenNoEntryFound() {
     // Other mocks

        every { // Here error occurs
            moneyCalculator.sum(emptyList<AccountingJournalLineMoney>())
        } returns Money(
            creditAmount = BigDecimal.ZERO,
            debitAmount = BigDecimal.ZERO,
            currency = Currency.AED
        )

        val actual = service.getJournalLinesAsResponsePayload(
            "company".Id,
            "sync".Id,
            mockk()
        )
    }

}



open class AbstractAccountingUnitTest {

    protected val companyId = "company".Id
    protected val regularCycleId = "regularCycle".Id
    protected val synchronizationId = "synchronization".Id

    @BeforeEach
    open fun setup() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
    }
}
```